# Positioning 3d objects for AR in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm experimenting with an AR experience in Unity3D. I'd like to place models in my Unity scene and have them show up on top of real world objects using tango. I'm using tango's augmentedReality scene as a starting point.

Say there is a table in a room and I want a 3d cube to sit on top of it when it is in tangos view. Do I need to be using an .adf file to solve this problem or is there something else I should be looking into.

Is there some way to test an .adf file locally in my unity scene? This would be ideal to establish and debug the correct positions to place models in my scene.

Just trying to sort everything out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep your virtual object's position persistent between different runs of the application, you will need a ADF file to relocalize. Unfortunately, there's no in-editor debug functions for ADF at the moment, so you will need to create a program to place the objects.

You could take a look of the [Experiments/PersistentState](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/ExperimentalProjects) example for reference. This  example is not using AR, however, it's saving objects position with respect to your ADF's origin and keeping them persistently.